# Vim get first line in a register

Tags: vimrc

I have a multi-line string that I'm reading by:

```
let a = getreg('*')
```

What would be the best way to get the first line of that string? I was hoping I could do something like:

- match
- getbufline

But am having trouble finding the necessary string function to do this. In python it'd be something like: `str.split('\n')[0]`

If helpful, when I do `echom a` the output looks like:

[image]

Also, what is `^@` in vim? I've seen `^M` for linebreak (return) but have never seen `^@` before.

**Update**: After some investigation it seems like that's the `nul` or `\0` byte, and can be entered in by doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>. And I ended up using this:

```
let first_line = matchstr(register, '\v<[^\n]+>')
```

It's very odd that this regex is what's used, as I tried doing something basic like `\v^.+$' and although it would work on a search page, it returned no results when I tried to search the register with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I prefer `let a = getreg('*', 1, 1)[0]` which is a bit shorter than `let a = split(getreg('*'), "\n")[0]` and does the same thing.

However, in your case the register contents for some reason contains Nul bytes (see `:h NL-used-for-Nul`). Hence you have to split on Nul manually: `let a = split(getreg('*'), '^@')[0]`

Comment: oh that's so much better/easier than what I came up with, thank you! What is the second arg in `getreg` ? In `:h` it just says `1` and nothing else (the third argument seems to be whether to return it as a string (default) or list (1).

Comment: @David542 It's for expression register (=) only. `getreg('=', 1)` will return expression itself, not its result, if I remember it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
^@
```

The null byte 0x00. Due to various things at the source-code level, newlines get embedded as null bytes in certain things (not all strings, since you can use `^M`, as you know).

Comment: I would very much appreciate a more detailed answer that could explain why and when this occurs, but I don’t have it, so I’ll leave this here in the meantime

Comment: Ben -- cool, yes I learned how to enter that in too, which was cool. So, would the best way to get the first line be to do: `a[0:match(a, '^@')-1]` ? That seems a bit hack-y but wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Comment: although when I actually run it in the function, `echom match(a, '^@')` that fails with a `Missing quote: '\` (though it runs on the command input??)

Comment: @David542 honestly im not sure